# Float com precisão PHP

Tags: php, float, arredondamento

Estou trazendo do banco de dados a soma dos valores e como resultado ele me retorna conforme o exemplo abaixo:

> 6.3285714285714

Gostaria de que ele ficasse dessa forma:

> 6.32

Já tentei o `ceil()` e o `round()`, mas ambos me retornaram para mais ou para menos. Tentei usar o `substr($valor,0,4);`, mas o problema é quando o valor fica:

> 6.328

Lembrando que o valor pode retornar também:

> 16.3285714285714

E acredito que o `substr()` não seria a solução. Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: tente desta forma substr($valor+0,4);

Comment: Obrigado Willian, mas a solução do Maniero foi a que melhor se adaptou.

Comment: Excelente, aprendizado para eu também! haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De fato falta um função para truncar no PHP, fizeram uma [no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12710283/221800) (não analisei se é boa mas parece):

```
function truncate($val, $f = "0") {
    if (($p = strpos($val, '.')) !== false) {
        $val = floatval(substr($val, 0, $p + 1 + $f));
    }
    return $val;
}
echo truncate(6.3285714285714, 2);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uRXCHB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/whzawqkf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Truncate.php).

Comment: Perfeito Maniero. Funcionou!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Mais uma vez me salvando, obrigado Maniero!

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que neste caso não teria que arredondar?

```
$valor = 6.3285714285714;
echo number_format(floatval($valor), 2, '.', '');
```

Agora se não quer arredondar é só fazer assim:

```
echo number_format(floor(($valor*100))/100, 2, '.', '');
```